# How to create Snapshot of disk using YAML syntax in GCE..?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-developers-console, google-developer-tools

My code:-

```
resources:

  name: snapshot-4

  type: compute.v1.disk

  properties:

   zone: asia-south1-a

   Kind: compute#snapshot

   sourceDisk: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/project-id/zones/asia-south1-a/disks/disk1
```

But it is creating Disk.. i want the snapshot of the disk1..

Answer (score 0):

The only two supported ways to create Persistent Disk [snapshots](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/disks/createSnapshot) are via the API and via REST or client libraries. At this time there is no possibility to create a PD snapshot using the YAML. However I can recommend you to create a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) in the Google Cloud Platform issue tracker to review your request.